# Promise inside forEach

Tags: node.js, meteor

```
  Current.senders.forEach(sender => {
    let UserList = Meteor.users.findOne({"_id":sender});
    console.log(UserList.profile.name)
  });
```

It will go through senders of Document A, will search profile.name on document B.

The problem is i only get the first one the other are undifined.

Is there a way to get them with a promise ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `async/await` to make the promise to wait, in case you need the `find` to be ran one after another.

```
Current.senders.forEach((sender) => {
  const UserList = await Meteor.users.findOne({"_id":sender});

  console.log(UserList.profile.name);
});
```

---

Either you can use `Promise.all` to run all your `find` simultaneously and then deal with the return.

```
const UserLists = await Promise.all(Current.senders.map(sender => Meteor.users.findOne({ "_id": sender })));
```

or

```
Promise.all(Current.senders.map(sender => Meteor.users.findOne({ "_id": sender })))
  .then((UserLists) => {
     // Deals with ok
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     // Deals with error
  });
```

`UserLists` here contains all the `find` results in an array.

Comment: Thank you for the response i tried the first one but i always get await is reserved word

Comment: It's because it needs to be inside an `async` function. Google `async/await node.js`

Answer (score 1):

```
// helper function to keep the rest of the code neat
const findUserBySender = sender => Meteor.users.findOne({"_id": sender});


async function test() {
    // run all searches in parallel via .map(), and await the overall result
    let userList = await Promise.all(Current.senders.map(findUserBySender));
    console.log(userList);
}
```

Instead of async/await you can of course use `Promise.all(...).then(userList => { ... })`.

Comment: I'm getting await is a reserved word

Comment: You need to run code that uses `await` in an `async` function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await